# change dbgrid options at runtime

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, dbgrid

I want to change the DBGrid.Option.I found the following code:

```
DBGrid.Options:=DBGrid.Options + [dgEditing];
DBGrid.Options:=[dgEditing];
```

But do not work properly and the error [dgEditing].
I want to enable or disable the [dgEditing],[dgRowSelect] mode.

thanks a lot, a lot.

Comment: What does not function?

ENABLE: DBGrid.Options := DBGrid.Options + [dgEditing];
DISABLE: DBGrid.Options := DBGrid.Options - [dgEditing];
ENABLE: DBGrid.Options := DBGrid.Options + [dgRowSelect];
DISABLE: DBGrid.Options := DBGrid.Options - [dgRowSelect];

ENABLE BOTH: DBGrid.Options := DBGrid.Options + [dgEditing, dgRowSelect];

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When working with set types, this is how you do :

```
DBGrid.Options := DBGrid.Options + [dgEditing];  // Adds dbEditing option

DBGrid.Options := DBGrid.Options - [dgEditing];  // Removes dbEditing option
```

To change several options at once :

```
DBGrid.Options := DBGrid.Options + [dgEditing,dgRowSelect]; 
DBGrid.Options := DBGrid.Options + [dgEditing] + [dgRowSelect]; // Same as above
```

Comment: woooow! I wrote code in another unit and a unit Vcl.DBGrids was not added. The unit must be added the The unit must be added the x in the list of uses. in the list of uses.Thanks very nice example.